# can't select armature bones in weight paint mode?

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

so for some reason, i can't select individual bones in weight paint mode (i'm on Blender 2.82 currently). I created my armature myself and pretty much left the default bone settings as is, aside from checking the "In Front" option in the viewport. I'm also using the default mouse button settings for 2.8, not the ones from 2.7

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

first select the bones then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> the mesh then go into *Weight Paint* mode and to select a bone just <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> it .

Comment: that's what i did. it didn't select any bones.